# Text Filtering in PubNub Twitter Data Stream

Tags: javascript, sentiment-analysis, pubnub

I am working on a simple demo that scans tweets based from the PubNub Twitter Stream on keywords like 'sad' (negative) or happy (positive) and then visualizes them on a map with the location in the US, as explained in this link:
https://blog.twitter.com/2014/tweet-emotion-real-time-tweet-analysis-with-pubnub-data-stream

What I'm trying to do, is adding the function to filter upon words or phrases. Like, for example, if I wanted to see the sentimented tweets about Donald Trump, I also want to be able to only pick out tweets that are also mentioning "Donald Trump".

Would somebody maybe have a suggestion on how to implement this in the javascript code? Which is provided here:

https://github.com/pubnub/tweet-emotion/tree/gh-pages/js

Any suggestion is more than welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add code like:

```
var trumpWords = ['Donald Trump', 'Mr. Trump', 'Trump'];

var trumpFace = {
    type: 'republican',
    icon: 'trump-face.png'
};

function processData(...) {
   ...
        } else if (trumpWords.some(function(v) { return data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) !== -1; })) {
        displayData(data, republican);
```

Then in the code you could track republican or democrat instead of positive and negative.  Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: Hey, thank for your reply! Greatly appreciated! :)

I've got it running so far.

Would you also have an idea on how I could implement this in the code, if I would wanna do both the positive/negative and the republican/democrat?